# How many views are required as I have a view showing drawing required, do I still need surfaceview

Tags: android, view, canvas, surfaceview

I have already created a circle with the use of a `View` and have not used `SurfaceView` at all. I want to create buttons which when clicked on show images from the drawables. But I have read on the net that a `SurfaceView` is required to allow UI elements to be placed on top. Is this true, can someone please help me, as I am confused on this.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question but you don't need a `SurfaceView` for drawing UI elements on top of each other.

Comment: So is it possible for me to continue using View which has been implemented and yet place UI elements, as I keep getting errors. The issue is I have drawn a circle shape on canvas in View and am trying to create a button below but the button overlaps the canvas causing only one to be shown. What can be done in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you want to do, but if you want to place UI elements on top of each other without using SurfaceView you can you a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html), this layout allows you to have views on top of each other, do you can have an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) with a drawable appearing over a button for example.

If you just want to change the background/src images of a button when clicked (for example to create a 3d effect of clicking), you can check out [selectors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html), these allows you to specify different drawables for pressed/normal states.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have already tried using the Relative Layout but the button covered the canvas and when I remove the button the canvas appears back.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create buttons on a `SurfaceView`, I suggest you render Bitmaps that will represent buttons. You will have to programmatically check if the touch coordinates are in the bounds of that bitmap tough, to register a button click.

I hope this helps.